# Where can I post feature request to the Azure Search dev team?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Where can I post feature request to the Azure Search dev team?

Found this, but its seems to be dead, or?
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/9325d19e-0225-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct website for feature requests. You can sort by "newest" to see recent posts.